# Optimizing loop for vba macro excel 2007

Tags: .net, vb.net, vba, excel

I have this code that works. it goes down a range and deletes the empty rows, seperates the first character into a different column if its not a number or negative sign.
This code WORKS. but it is too SLOW for the amount of data i need it to deal with. 
Thank you anyone for your suggestion on how to optimize this code and make it faster.

I have already turned off automatic calculations. screen updating. and visibility of application.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim Tracking As Long

Dim textval As String
Dim limitz As String
Dim remaining As String

Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5).Select

Set rng = Range("G2", ActiveCell).Select

i = 1
Range("G2").Select

For Tracking = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

    textval = rng.Cells(i).Value
    limitz = Left(textval, 1)

    If limitz = "" Then
      rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
     ElseIf limitz <> "0" And limitz <> "1" And limitz <> "2" And limitz <> "3" And limitz <> "4" And limitz <> "5" And limitz <> "6" And limitz <> "7" And limitz <> "8" And limitz <> "9" And limitz <> "-" Then
      remaining = Right(textval, Len(textval) - 1)
      rng.Cells(i) = remaining
      rng.Cells(i).Offset(0, 1).Value = limitz
      i = i + 1
     Else
      i = i + 1
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not so much code that seems to be *obviously inefficient*.

Here is some tips about what I can tell:

- **Don't select cells** unless you are really forced too (as it is not within your loop, that is not the worst thing)
- Try to parse `range` instead of using a *Long*
- Change your test with a vba statement like `IsNumeric`
- Use `With` to avoid calling an object multiple times

Here is a try (i may have changed some behavior because i couldn't understand if you wanted to parse cells or rows):

```
Sub test()
  Dim rng As Range, row As Range
  Dim i As Long

  Dim textval As String
  Dim limitz As String
  Dim remaining As String

  Set rng = Range("G2", Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5))
  i = 1

  For Each row In rng.Rows
      With row
        textval = .Cells(i).Value
        limitz = Left(textval, 1)

        If limitz = "" Then
            .Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf limitz <> "-" And Not IsNumeric(limitz) Then
          remaining = Right(textval, Len(textval) - 1)
          With .Cells(i)
            .Value = remaining
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = limitz
          End With
          i = i + 1
         Else
          i = i + 1
        End If
      End With
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Jmax for always helping me out. unfortunately im quite the beginner at coding >.> started july when i started my work term. would u be able to provide me examples of parse? is numeric and with  inside the code  or used in other code??    i remebr trying is numeric but it didnt work for me i probably used it wrong and i have never heard of partse and with.

Comment: i've edited my answer to show an example of what your code could look like. Don't hesitate to tell us if something goes wrong so we could fix it (it may takes a day or two depending wether i'm coming here)

Comment: Good suff as usual JMax! +1 ^^

Answer (score 2):

You should process your rows from the bottom to the top: should be faster beacause each delete causes fewer rows to move up.

Untested:

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim Tracking As Long

    Dim textval As String
    Dim limitz As String

    Set rng = Range("G2", Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5))
    numRows = rng.Rows.Count

    For Tracking = numRows To 1 Step -1

        Set c = rng.Cells(Tracking)
        textval = c.Value
        limitz = Left(textval, 1)

        If limitz = "" Then
          c.EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Not limitz Like "[0-9-]" Then
          c.Value = Right(textval, Len(textval) - 1)
          c.Offset(0, 1).Value = limitz
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: smart note on the bottom up part!

Comment: i think im actually going with your code here. i tried all the codes and this one seems to work, and fastest atm ! Thank you Tim

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty speedy. Hope I didn't alter your code too much to change something I shouldn't have.

Grabbing all the data in a variant makes it much faster since the VBA doesn't have to interact with Excel too much. Using special cells also does this. Using "like" cleans the code up, don't know if the performance is any better for that.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim vData As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim limitz As String

Set rng = Range("G2", Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5).Address)

'Delete empty cells
On Error Resume Next
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

'Get all data in range
vData = rng.Resize(, 2)

For i = 1 To UBound(vData)

    limitz = Left$(CStr(vData(i, 1)), 1)

    If limitz Like "[!0-9,!-]" Then
      vData(i, 1) = Right$(CStr(vData(i, 1)), Len(vData(i, 1)) - 1)
      vData(i, 2) = limitz
    End If
Next

rng.Resize(, 2) = vData
```

The following code is untested but should work and go pretty fast. It should be noted that deleted entire rows is fairly costly (time wise) to do, although you can minimize the time using the method below, it will still take a while and there's not much you can do about it:

```
dim bUnion as boolean
Dim rng As Range, rUnion as range
Dim vData As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim limitz As String

Set rng = Range("G2", Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5).Address)

'Get all data in range
vData = rng.Resize(, 2)

bunion=false
For i = 1 To UBound(vData)

    if len(vdata(i,1))>0 THEN
      limitz = Left$(CStr(vData(i, 1)), 1)

      If limitz Like "[!0-9,!-]" Then
        vData(i, 1) = Right$(CStr(vData(i, 1)), Len(vData(i, 1)) - 1)
        vData(i, 2) = limitz
      End If
    else
      if bunion then 
          set runion=union(runion,range("A" & i+1))
      else
          set runion=range("A" & i+1)
          bunion=true
      end if
    end if
Next

rng.Resize(, 2) = vData
runion.entirerow.delete
```

Comment: Dang, I always take too long to get these answers out. The code I posted should be the fastest one out of all the solutions, unfortunately I take too long to get these answers out! It's amazing how fast people answer them!

Comment: Thanks Jon. i think the second part of yoru code is really fast but the first part with the special cells. because i can have like 10 0000s of blanks in a row befoer it reaches another value . it dosent select these blanks only if there are like a few between each value

Comment: Hmm, I guess I would have to take tackle it differently. I'm working on your other one right now that you just posted. Hopefully after a few of these you'll see and understand the methods we are using to make them go so quickly. If I were to redo this one I would make a range that and use the function "union" to combine the range of all the blanks. Don't know why it isn't deleted the blanks, it should, maybe because they are not "truly" blank? Like they have "" inside the cell.

Comment: o probably that might be so its weird tho that some still delete then i wonder why.     before this code ran i had actually combined two columns to form this one we are doing right now.  and these data were gathered from this other source so maybe someone inputted a blank or osmething .  Thanks jon i look forward to your answer for the other one!

Comment: So is there an equation in the cells then? That might do it. I'll edit my code above so you can see the other alternative that is pretty fast.

Comment: Actually no no equations in the cell cuz i copied then paste specialed it with values only ?

Comment: @Jon49: you're right. Stackoverflow posters are *really really* fast. But your answer is still very valuable and desserves a +1 :)